# flutter split long text into pages

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Today I've been working with JSON for a book app and came across long text. these JSON objects display a book and I want to show those text objects as one. means to display it as a book. so how can I display and make a book app?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57620603/15117201

Comment: I've tried that. doesn't work, actually it doesn't specify the Document keyword

Comment: are you able to parse the text? what is the current state of code-snippet

Comment: I get the text from JSON object.